# How to Sort XML feed alphabetically

Tags: html, xml, parsing

I'm trying to sort an XML feed alphabetically by "LastName" without creating an XSLT template, I have the below code, but it returns and error.

```
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://showcast.com.au/showcast/webservice/actors.aspx?agencyId=&Password=",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXml
        });
    });

    function parseXml(xml){
        $(xml).find("artist").each(function(){
                var nx_name = $(this).find("FirstName").text() + ' ' + $(this).find("LastName").text();
                var nx_pic = '';
                $(this).find("Photos SmallPhotos Photo").each(function(){
                    if( $(this).find("IsDefault").text() == "True" ){
                        nx_pic = $(this).find("Url").text();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                var nxlink = $(this).find("URLlink").text();
                var nxhtml = '<div class="nxitem"><a href="'+nxlink+'" class="nxclearfix"><div class="nxwrap"><div class="nximgwrap"><img src="'+nx_pic+'"></div></div><br/><span class="nxname">'+nx_name+'</span></a></div>';
                $("#nxdisplay").append(nxhtml);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and copy+paste the error message. If you didn't share it because you don't think it's relevant to your problem, explain that as well.

Comment: Maybe you don't want to paste user User IDs and passwords into a public page?